# Reading list of files in a directory into a char array

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to get a list of files in the directory with some string formatting. Currently, Like so.

```c
#define BUFFER 4096

void ListDir(){
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE hFind;
    hFind = FindFirstFile("*", &data);
    char* dir = calloc(1, BUFFER);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        snprintf(dir, BUFFER, "RHPDIR<>%s\n", cDir());
        do {
            int len = strlen(dir);
          
            if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                snprintf(dir + len, sizeof(dir) - len, "[DIRECTORY] %s\n", data.cFileName);
            }
            else {
                ULONGLONG FileSize = data.nFileSizeHigh;
                FileSize <<= sizeof(data.nFileSizeHigh) * 8;
                FileSize |= data.nFileSizeLow;
                snprintf(dir + len, sizeof(dir) - len, "[FILE] %s (%llu bytes)\n", data.cFileName, FileSize);
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));

        sockSend(dir);
        if (dir)
        {
            free(dir);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that reading directories that have more files, Especially large directories such as System32, the buffer overflows. I know I need to increase the size of `dir`. But I don't understand how I can do this.

**Goal** :
To get a buffer containing all files and directories from any directory

**What I've tried** :
I had feeling this is a bad method, But I tried this hoping it would work. I made a function that returns the size of directory listing, And using that size to create a buffer. This worked for most directories, But still in System32 Directory, I got an overflow. Also I had to scan the directories twice for this. :s

```c
int returnCurrentDirFilesize()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE hFind;
    hFind = FindFirstFile("*", &data);
    int size = 0;
    char tmpbuf[BUFFER];
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        snprintf(tmpbuf, BUFFER, "RHPDIR<>%s\n", cDir());
        size += strlen(tmpbuf);

        do {
            if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {

                memset(tmpbuf, '\0', BUFFER);
                snprintf(tmpbuf, BUFFER, "[DIRECTORY] %s\n", data.cFileName);
                size += strlen(tmpbuf);

            }
            else {
                ULONGLONG FileSize = data.nFileSizeHigh;
                FileSize <<= sizeof(data.nFileSizeHigh) * 8;
                FileSize |= data.nFileSizeLow;

                memset(tmpbuf, '\0', BUFFER);
                snprintf(tmpbuf, BUFFER, "[FILE] %s (%llu bytes)\n", data.cFileName, FileSize);
                size += strlen(tmpbuf);
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));

        return size;
    }
}

void ListDir(){
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE hFind;
    hFind = FindFirstFile("*", &data);
    char* dir = calloc(1, BUFFER);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        snprintf(dir, BUFFER, "RHPDIR<>%s\n", cDir());
        do {
            int len = strlen(dir);
          
            if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                snprintf(dir + len, sizeof(dir) - len, "[DIRECTORY] %s\n", data.cFileName);
            }
            else {
                ULONGLONG FileSize = data.nFileSizeHigh;
                FileSize <<= sizeof(data.nFileSizeHigh) * 8;
                FileSize |= data.nFileSizeLow;
                snprintf(dir + len, sizeof(dir) - len, "[FILE] %s (%llu bytes)\n", data.cFileName, FileSize);
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));

        sockSend(dir);
        if (dir)
        {
            free(dir);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either use C++, or reinvent its `vector` implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable Can this not be done in C without implementing vector?

Comment: Of course this can be done in C, but the result will look a lot like C++' `vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use realloc function to accomplish that. I have edited your code below to show you how to use in order for this to be done

```
#define BUFFER 4096

void ListDir() 
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA data;
    HANDLE hFind;
    hFind = FindFirstFileA("C:\\windows\\system32\\*", &data);
    char* dir = calloc(BUFFER, sizeof(char));
    size_t dirSize = BUFFER;
    size_t dirIndex = 0;
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        snprintf(dir, BUFFER, "RHPDIR<>%s\n", "C:\\windows\\system32\\");
        dirIndex = strlen(dir);
        do {
            size_t currLineSize = 0;
            char currLine[MAX_PATH * 2] = { '\0' };

            if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                snprintf(currLine, sizeof(currLine), "[DIRECTORY] %s\n", data.cFileName);
            }
            else {
                ULONGLONG FileSize = data.nFileSizeHigh;
                FileSize <<= sizeof(data.nFileSizeHigh) * 8;
                FileSize |= data.nFileSizeLow;
                snprintf(currLine, sizeof(currLine), "[FILE] %s (%llu bytes)\n", data.cFileName, FileSize);
            }

            // here we check if our memory is enough to store new line or not
            // if not, reallocate buffer with a new size
            currLineSize = strlen(currLine);
            if (dirIndex + currLineSize + sizeof(char) >= dirSize) {
                char* tmp = dir;
                dirSize += BUFFER;
                dir = realloc(dir, dirSize);
                if (dir == NULL) {
                    // allocation error
                    free(tmp);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }

            strcat_s(dir, dirSize, currLine);
            dirIndex += currLineSize;

        } while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &data));

        // sockSend(dir);
        printf("%s", dir);
        if (dir)
        {
            free(dir);
        }
    }
}
```